# Why did Joab grip the ram horns of the altar?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, repentance-teshuvah, melachim-kings-book-of, mizbeach-altar

In Kings 2:28 it is written:

> When the news reached Joab, he fled to the Tent of the Lord and grasped the horns of the altar - for Joab had sided with Adonijah, though he had not sided with Absalom.

Clearly the altar is holy, and at this moment, Joab was aware that he was in danger. Why this action specifically, compared to offering a sacrifice or begging for forgiveness?

The only modern-day reference I can think of for the ram's horns is the shofar.

Comment: The Metzudat David said he did so because he figured that no one would defile the place by killing him there.

Comment: Then why did he say in King 2:30 that he will die in the Tent?

Comment: I would think that practically those are the easiest parts to hold on to?

Comment: "_Why this action specifically, compared to offering a sacrifice or begging for forgiveness?_" (1) Probably because he wasn't expecting to to be given a chance to do either. (2) Maybe he was hoping for a similar outcome to the one [that Adonijah got](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Kings.1.50-53?lang=bi&lang2=en).

Comment: @TamirEvan That second point draws a great comparison

Answer (score 1):

[Makkos 12A](https://www.sefaria.org/Makkot.12a.3?lang=bi):

> נגמר דינו וכו': אמר רב יהודה אמר רב שתי טעיות טעה יואב באותה שעה דכתיב (מלכים א ב, כח) וינס יואב אל אהל ה' ויחזק בקרנות המזבח

> § The mishna teaches: If the verdict of a murderer was decided at a time when there was no High Priest, and likewise in the cases of one who unintentionally killed a High Priest and in the case of a High Priest who killed unintentionally, the unintentional murderer never leaves the city of refuge. And one who is exiled may not leave the city at all; even if the Jewish people require his services, and even if he is the general of the army of the Jewish people like Joab ben Zeruiah, he does not leave the city of refuge ever. Rav Yehuda says that Rav says: Joab made two errors at that moment, when he fled from Solomon, as it is written: “And Joab fled to the Tent of God and grasped the horns of the altar” (I Kings 2:28).

> טעה שאינו קולט אלא גגו והוא תפס בקרנותיו טעה שאינו קולט אלא מזבח בית עולמים והוא תפס מזבח של שילה אביי אומר בהא נמי מיטעא טעה טעה שאינו קולט אלא כהן ועבודה בידו והוא זר היה

> He erred in that only the top of the altar provides refuge, and he grasped its corners. Moreover, he erred in that only the altar of the eternal House, i.e., the Temple. provides refuge, and he grasped the altar at Shiloh. Abaye said: It is with regard to this that Joab also erred, as the altar provides refuge only for a priest who grasps the roof of the altar and his service is in his hand, and Joab was a non-priest

Comment: So are you saying that Joab was attempting to find refuge, but did so in the wrong way?

Comment: That’s what the Gemara says

Comment: The Gemara does not seem to say that explicitly. In Kings 2:30 Joab explicitly declares that he wishes to die in the Tent